# Textbox that can only accept integer ranging from 00 - 60

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox

I want to validate the users input in a textbox by not accepting anything except integers ranging from 00 to 60.

**Conditions:**

1. If the user input 0 or input nothing the system should considered it as 00 (take note that I padded it with 0.
2. I know that I can do this also in `numericupdown`, but for some reason I can't use that.
3. I need to apply this in 20 textboxes.

This is the code, actually it is working. My only problem is I can't apply it to 20 textboxes, it is only working in tb_hour_1 textbox, is there something that I can do instead of indication `tb_hour_1.text` in this line of code `Dim num As Integer = Integer.Parse(String.Format("{0}{1}", If(Tb_Hour_1.Text = String.Empty, "", Tb_Hour_1.Text), e.KeyChar.ToString()))`.

**Code:**

```
    Private Sub Tb_Hour_1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Tb_Minute_2.KeyPress, Tb_Minute_1.KeyPress,
    Tb_Hour_2.KeyPress, Tb_Hour_1.KeyPress

    Dim Min_Num As Integer = 0
    Dim Max_Num As Integer = 60

    If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        'allow backspace for deleting
        e.Handled = Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)
        'allow numbers only
        If Not e.Handled Then
            Dim num As Integer = Integer.Parse(String.Format("{0}{1}", If(Tb_Hour_1.Text = String.Empty, "", Tb_Hour_1.Text), e.KeyChar.ToString()))
            If num < Min_Num OrElse num > Max_Num Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Using a common event handler for all TextBoxes is Ok. Just replace Tb_Hour_1 by a cast, i.e. Ctype(sender,TextBox).

Comment: you have a  hard coded reference to `Tb_Hour_1` use `sender` or a NumericUpDown

Comment: @Graffito, Your comment works for me. Please answer this question so I can make it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a common event handler for all TextBoxes is Ok. Just replace Tb_Hour_1 by a cast, i.e. :

```
Ctype(sender,TextBox)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should better create a UserControl for this purpose. which validates the input and range and instead of creating 20 textboxes, you can use your custom control then. Also, `MaskedTextBox` control can also be used to avoid checking length of text and it can only allow digits as well.

Also, a shortcut could be to list down all the remaining control's event like this:

```
Private Sub Tb_Hour_1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Tb_Minute_2.KeyPress, Tb_Minute_1.KeyPress,
    Tb_Hour_2.KeyPress, Tb_Hour_1.KeyPress, ....... further control events
```